# Why is my ajax request executed twice if have only on call?

Tags: php, ajax, request

I have an ajax request for a script in php, in this script I do several checks of the past values and right after I call a DAO method to save the information in the db, so far everything normal, the problem has been that when a of the validations fail I return an error with the echo json_enconde ($error) and use the exit(). What can go wrong? Well, even with the exit some strange behaviors happen, yes the $error is returned, but even with this return, the success function is triggered twice, one returns it to me and the other the script continues to be called and saves the infos in the db.

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "ajax/compra-acao.php",
    data: {usuario_id: usuario, cod: c, qtd: quantidade, acao: acao1},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            document.getElementById('btnComprar').disabled = false
            return 0;
        }
    },
    error: function(response, status, error){
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
})
```

SCRIPT PHP

```
    <?php

if(!isset($_POST['usuario_id']) || !isset($_POST['cod']) || !isset($_POST['qtd']) || !isset($_POST['acao'])){
    echo json_encode($retorno['erro'] = 'Houve um erro ao processar sua solicitação. POST');
    exit();
}

include_once('../PDO/acaoDAO.php');
include_once('../PDO/usuarioDAO.php');

$usuario = new UserBD();
$acao = new Acao();

$retorno = [];

$usuario = $usuario->getUserById($_POST['usuario_id']);

if(!$usuario){
    $retorno['erro'] = 'Houve um erro ao processar sua solicitação';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}

if(!password_verify($usuario[0]['cpf'], $_POST['cod'])){
    $retorno['erro'] = 'Hoje não, espertinho';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}

if($_POST['qtd'] < 1){
    $retorno['erro'] = 'Quantidade inválida';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}

$precoAcao = $acao->getPrecoAcaoById($_POST['acao']);

if(!$precoAcao){
    $retorno['erro'] = 'Ação inválida';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}

$saldo = $acao->getSaldoDinheiroById($_POST['usuario_id']);

if($saldo < (double) $precoAcao * (int) $_POST['qtd']){
    $retorno['erro'] = 'Saldo insuficiente';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
}

$result = $acao->compraAcao($_POST['qtd'], $_POST['acao'], $_POST['usuario_id'], $saldo[0]['quantidade'], $precoAcao[0]['preco']);

if(isset($result['erro'])){
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
}else{
    echo json_encode([true]);
    exit();
}

?>
```

When I use `console.log(response)` I get two exits, the first with the array with the error and right after a return `[true]`, which is when everything went right with the inserts in the db.

CONSOLE.LOG

```
{erro: "Hoje não, espertinho"} erro: "Hoje não, espertinho" __proto__: Object
preco.js:65 

[true] 0: true length: 1 __proto__: Array(0)
```

**EDIT:**

With the help of friends in the comments I could see that I was targeting efforts in the wrong place, when evaluating the tab network in the browser I could see that the request was being sent more than 1 time, with the wrong value and with the right value too, that's why the double execution.

Comment: Is the AJAX request being sent twice?  Check the network tab in the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: I'll check, but anyway, even if it was sent twice, it should return two errors and not proceed to the db

Comment: Unless the two AJAX requests include different data, producing different results.  (Or if you're saying it should *never* proceed to the DB then I imagine simply removing that part of the PHP code would work just as well.)

Comment: Something is calling the AJAX code twice. The first one gets an error, the second one succeeds.

Comment: In the tab network there are 2 requests for the php script, even with 1 click on the button, one with an error and the other with success

Comment: Put a breakpoint before the call to `$.ajax`. Then you'll be able to see where it's being called from.

Comment: @David proceed to DB only if the data is correct

Comment: @SávioMendesMiranda: Then it's time to take a step back and do some more debugging, because the premise of the question (asking why `exit()` doesn't work) is false and unanswerable.  Currently the question assumes that any client-side code not shown here must be correct, but observations have demonstrated otherwise.

Comment: Look at the parameters in the two requests in the Network tab. The second one presumably has valid parameters, so it doesn't get any validation errors and is stored in the DB.

Comment: @David 
I will change

Comment: @Barmar You're right, that's what happens

Comment: So you need to debug why the ajax code is being run twice. The JavaScript debugger in the browser is perfect for this.

Comment: None of the code you've posted so far is relevant to this. You need to investigate where the `$.ajax` code is being called from.

Comment: I tested it in another browser, it works normally, only in Google Chrome is like this

Comment: @SávioMendesMiranda: Or it works normally in Google Chrome and only in that one other browser is there strange behavior.  Be careful about your assumptions, because that's what brought you here in the first place.  If you've tested the code in two browsers and seen two different results then you have no indication of what is "normal" and what isn't.  In either case, you're looking in the wrong place.  If the code is being invoked twice then you have to debug to discover how/why that's happening.  Looking at other browsers won't do that.  Debugging your JavaScript code will.

Comment: I managed to find out what was causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging better I could find the cause of the problem, it was really happening because of Google Chrome. The code is ok.

I wanted to force the sending of wrong data to the server and I was doing it using the function of inspecting chrome element and placing any value manually, it happens that when changing the value in this way Chrome ends up "stacks" or "adds" one more call the function of AJAX, if I change this way several times it will stack more and more calls, I don't know if it should be the correct behavior

The HTML with the call:

```
<button id="btnVender" onclick="venderAcao(210,'5mbZz5LpULCs9oKT3BHbzUiW',3)" class="btn btn-vender mt-xl-0 mt-lg-3 mt-0">Vender</button>
```

if I change any of these values of the onclick function it is as if I have two functions being called in the onclick, the original and the modified one

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `exit;` with out '()' or `return false;` or `return;`
and put to befor your exit the

```
http_response_code(500);
echo json_encode('ERROR');
exit;
```